# In VBScript, how do I manage "Scripting.FileSystemObjects" like objFSO and objFolder for multiple folders/files?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, multiple-instances, filesystemobject

In VBScript, how do I manage "Scripting.FileSystemObjects" like objFSO and objFolder for multiple folders/files ?

In the "Main" code section, I declare an instance (global) of "Scripting.FileSystemObject"

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Then, I perform some operations, like:

```
    If objFSO.FileExists(strOutputFilename) Then
        WScript.Echo "Deleting File: " & strOutputFilename
        objFSO.DeleteFile strOutputFilename
    End If
```

Then, in a loop, I get a folder, and pass it to a function:

```
    For gintLoop = 0 to (ubound(arraySearchPath))
        wscript.echo "Processing folder:" & arraySearchPath(gintLoop)
        Set objFolderX = objFSO.GetFolder(arraySearchPath(gintLoop))
        Call DoWork (objFolderX, arrayParam1, arrayParam2)
    Next
```

So far everything is clear...

Now, within the function, I do things like:
a) collect filenames from objFolder

```
    Set lobjFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFolderX.Path)  
    Set lcolFiles = lobjFolder.Files
```

b) check for existance of files in other (unrelated) paths

c) get the size of various files:

```
    lcurInputFileSize = CCur(lobjFile.Size)
```

d) delete various files

e) open files for reading

```
    For Each lobjFile in lcolFiles
        lstrTargetFile = lobjFolder.Path & "\" & lobjFile.Name
        Set lobjInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(lstrTargetFile, ForReading)
    ...
```

f) open files for writing

```
    Set lobjOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFilename, ForAppending, True)
```

g) call other subs/functions passing various object

h) recursively call the (same) function to process other folders

```
    For Each lobjSubfolderY in objFolderX.SubFolders
        Call DoWork (lobjSubfolderY, arrayParam1, arrayParam2)
    Next
```

My concern is that I need to make sure the various uses of FileSystemObjects like folder paths, open files, etc, are not "Stepped-on" by later uses of FileSystemObjects.

Question 1:
Do I need (or is it advised) to have a seperate instance of "Scripting.FileSystemObject" (objFSO) for "Main" and each (or some) sub/function ?

Question 2:
Similarly, how do I manage the various other objects to avoid loosing data ?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**:  No, you do not need multiple instances of Scripting.FileSystemObject.

The methods on the object  are all static.

In fact, the documentation for the Scripting Runtime Reference indicates that the FSO is a *singleton*, although it does not use the word:

> You can create only one instance of the FileSystemObject object, regardless of how many times you try to create another.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx

In my experience, calling `WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` multiple times does not result in an error. Likely the return value on subsequent calls is just a copy of the originally created FSO.

As for your Question 2, I don't get it.  I think you are referring to objects that are returned by FSO, objects of type Folder, File, TextStream and so on.

Treat these like any other stateful object. You can have multiple instances, and you need to pass them as stack-based arguments if you  want to do recursion.

Comment: Q1:Thanks... I have seen conflicting info on creating multiple objFSO. This is the first time anyone has referred a document that explains and confirms it. Q2:Yes, I was talking about Folder, File, etc. ...  As far as: "stack-based arguments", do you mean the items passed as arguments to the sub/function calls ? ... I assume these should be "ByRef" rather than "ByVal".

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.  Objects will be passed by ref, but that's not what you need to worry about. Just focus on maintaining a distinct object instance for each file or folder you're fiddling with.

Comment: With your help, I was able to sort things out, thanks again. I also found an objFile in the Recursive function that was always being "Set" for the same file (logfile). So, I changed that one to be Dim(med) in the "Main" program so it is now a global object.